# PHP file_get_contents filename start with special char

Tags: php, file-get-contents

i am trying to understand what is happeninng when i using file_get_contents
with filename parameter
i'm starting it with ? or ! or any special char
it is working successfuly but something weired.
this is something what i did.

```
heogi@ubuntu:~$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > $a = file_get_contents("../../index.html");
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(../../index.html): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in php shell code on line 1
php > $a = file_get_contents("?../../index.html");
php > echo $a;
hello test;

heogi@ubuntu:~$ pwd
/home/heogi

heogi@ubuntu:~$ ls -l
total 28
drwxr-xr-x  8 root  root   4096 Sep 18 16:36 dirsearch
-rw-rw-r--  1 heogi heogi 12918 Nov 19 10:56 index.html
drwxr-xr-x 11 root  root   4096 Sep 18 16:35 sqlmap-dev
drwxr-xr-x  4 root  root   4096 Sep 18 16:13 Sublist3r

heogi@ubuntu:~$ php -version
PHP 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.7 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.7, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

why is it work only it start with special char?
and even it need change directory why is it ?

Comment: Looks like `index.html` is right in the same folder with you. Why are you trying to open it from another folder?

Comment: that is a just test
i mean why it is same that

$a = file_get_contents("/home/heogi/index.html");
$a = file_get_contents("?../../index.html);

it is open same file that /home/heogi/index.html

Comment: What returns this: var_dump(realpath("?../../index.html"));

Comment: `php > var_dump(realpath("?../../index.html"));
bool(false)`
it returns false i think ?../../ is only works in file_get_contents filename parameter

Comment: `file_get_contents` can retrieve URLs, I wonder if it's seeing the ? at the beginning and somehow thinking that it's a URL fragment and sending it to localhost or something.

Comment: i think you are right. i did new test
`echo "whywhywhy?" > test.txt` and did this
`php > $a = file_get_contents("?https://google.com/../../test.txt");
php > echo $a;
whywhywhy?`
it looks like sending to localhost.